# How does servlet handle multiple uploaded files in one request

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I know how to save it when only one file is uploaded in servlet.
HTML

```
<form action="storeArticle" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    ...
</form>
```

Servlet can save the uploaded file as follows:

```
Part part = request.getPart("file");
File file = new File(filePath);
try (InputStream inputStream= part.getInputStream()) { // save uploaded file
    Files.copy(inputStream, file.toPath());
}
```

For example, in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, user can choose uploading multiple images by clicking the only one image icon.But when multiple files are uploaded one time, how can servlet save these uploaded files?
HTML

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="storeArticle" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="file" name="file2">
<input type="file" name="file3">

</form>
```

The servlet does this

```
Part part = request.getPart("file");
 File file = new File(filePath);
 try (InputStream inputStream= part.getInputStream()) { // save uploaded file
  Files.copy(inputStream, file.toPath());
 }


  Part part = request.getPart("file2");
  File file = new File(filePath);
 try (InputStream inputStream= part.getInputStream()) { // save uploaded file
  Files.copy(inputStream, file.toPath());
 }



  Part part = request.getPart("file3");
  File file = new File(filePath);
  try (InputStream inputStream= part.getInputStream()) { // save uploaded file
    Files.copy(inputStream, file.toPath());
   }
```

Comment: The HTML would show 3 elements, which is not what I want. For example, in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, user can choose uploading multiple images by only one image icon.